# Run two executables in parallel

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run two exe programs in parallel. I want to start them, wait for them to complete before continuing on. Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ProcessStartInfo proc1Info = new ProcessStartInfo("Testexe.exe");
   proc1Info.ErrorDialog = false;
   proc1Info.UseShellExecute = false;
   proc1Info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   proc1Info.RedirectStandardError = true;
   proc1Info.Arguments = "5000";

   ProcessStartInfo proc2Info = new ProcessStartInfo("Testexe1.exe");
   proc2Info.ErrorDialog = false;
   proc2Info.UseShellExecute = false;
   proc2Info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   proc2Info.RedirectStandardError = true;
   proc2Info.Arguments = "10000";

   Console.WriteLine("Start Proc 1"); 
   Process proc1 = new Process();
   proc1.StartInfo = proc1Info;
   var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => proc1.Start());

   Console.WriteLine("Start Proc 2"); 
   Process proc2 = new Process();
   proc2.StartInfo = proc2Info;
   var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => proc2.Start());

   Console.WriteLine("Wait for tasks");
   Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
   Console.WriteLine("Procs complete");
}
```

The first proc is going to sleep 5 seconds and the second proc for 10 seconds. I expected to see the two messages that the procs had started and the message "Wait for tasks". Then 10 seconds later see "Procs complete". However, I see "Procs complete" immediately.

Task manager shows the procs running while "Procs complete" is displayed.

So, how do I start two separate executable programs from a single program, run them in parallel and then wait for them to complete before I continue on?

Comment: Found the solution. Use "proc1.WatForExit()" and "proc2.WaitForExit()".

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       ProcessStartInfo proc1Info = new ProcessStartInfo("Testexe.exe");
       proc1Info.ErrorDialog = false;
       proc1Info.UseShellExecute = false;
       proc1Info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       proc1Info.RedirectStandardError = true;
       proc1Info.Arguments = "5000";

```
   ProcessStartInfo proc2Info = new ProcessStartInfo("Testexe1.exe");
   proc2Info.ErrorDialog = false;
   proc2Info.UseShellExecute = false;
   proc2Info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   proc2Info.RedirectStandardError = true;
   proc2Info.Arguments = "10000";

   Console.WriteLine("Start Proc 1"); 
   Process proc1 = new Process();
   proc1.StartInfo = proc1Info;
   proc1.Start();

   Console.WriteLine("Start Proc 2"); 
   Process proc2 = new Process();
   proc2.StartInfo = proc2Info;
   proc2.Start();

   Console.WriteLine("Wait for Procs");
   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();
   proc1.WaitForExit();
   proc2.WaitForExit();
   sw.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine("Procs complete in '{0}' ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```